# .net Maui Image in class library

Tags: maui

I am porting a WPF application to a .net MAUI application that uses a .net MAUI class library to load a ContentView.  The library contains an image that I want to display in the ContentView.  I use images in the MAUI application, but how do I access and display an image in a class library?

I added the image (.PNG) to the class library with a build action of MauiImage and also as Embedded resource and used:
for embedded resource:

```
 <Border StrokeThickness="3">
        <Image Source="ATool.Resources.Images.test.png" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100"/>
 </Border>
```

and

```
 <Border StrokeThickness="3">
        <Image Source="test.png"/>
 </Border>
```

I can see the border but not the image.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: this is covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image#load-an-embedded-image-in-xaml)

Comment: @Jason, doc doesn’t mention class library.

Comment: it's an **embedded image**, it doesn't matter what kind of project its embedded in